# Should I give my pets vitamins or other supplements?

Tags: cats, health, diet

I want my cat to live long and I'm thinking of giving her human vitamins and supplements.  Sadly, all cat foods like Meow Mix and Fancy Feast don't have vitamins added, and considering that *in nature processed foods don't exist and animals get a lot of sunlight*, I think that most human pets are vitamin deprived unknowing to their owner, even if they appear healthy.

I think I should like give my pets fish oil (like those omega 6 acids that are fat) and vitamins to help them have them live long and healthy lives.

I want to know if its safe to give these vitamins:

- **Vitamin D** and here's why: guess where Vitamin D is found in nature?  In meat?  Nope... actually it is found **in fish**, and also (you can google it if you don't believe me), sunlight exposure.  People who are indoors are usually deprived of vitamin d.  And what do cats eat in nature: *vitamins and sunlight*... they don't sit indoors all day long eating vitamin deprived processed meat
- **Fish oil**, and according to google it is called "Omega-6 Fatty Acids", and in the wild cats get lots of fish oil, since wild cats eat fish and that's their favorite food.
- **Vitamin B6**, my cat was smart but I believe that giving her vitamins that are neuroprotective is very good for her and can make her EVEN SMARTER.
- **5-htp** my cat isn't aggressive but just so she was less stressed...

My cat was always healthy but I believe that if i give vitamins and fish oil and drugs like 5-htp it will live to be like 40 years old... because **if a human child only survived on processed meat all their lives starting from being a kid**... do u think they wood die at age 8 or at age 80? i think at age 8. and not to mention that processed cat food is probably much worse then chicken McNuggets since i think they would be investing less in animal safety then into human safety.

Sadly they don't sell vitamins and supplements for pets, so I'm considering products sold for humans.

***tl;dr*:**  I want to know if it is safe to give 5-htp, fish oil, Vitamin B6, and Vitamin D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, don't give your pets human drugs

Animals have very different nutritional requirements and tolerances.  Cats need different things, and due to their significantly smaller body size, they need very different dose sizes.

In some specific cases, reducing the dose size can be sufficient.  But that's a very case-by-case thing that needs to be researched.

Most drugs and nutritional supplements aren't shown to really help humans at the recommended dosages, so it's very unlikely that they'll somehow help an otherwise-healthy cat.  Realistically, you're probably either going to poison your pet or have no real effect on it.  Hopefully it's the latter.

Answer (score 4):

It is *absolutely* worth checking with a vet first, since animals have issues with very different substances than humans, and many things are body weight dependant.

*Some* of your premises are incorrect though

> sunlight exposure. People who are indoors are usually deprived of vitamin d. And what do cats eat in nature: vitamins and sunlight... they don't sit indoors all day long eating vitamin deprived processed meat

Cats don't actually [make vitamin D](http://pets.thenest.com/cats-absorbing-vitamin-d-lying-sun-10489.html) in their skin from sunlight like we do. High levels can also be [lethal](http://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/toxicity/c_ct_vitamin_d_toxicity)

fish oil is probably *not* bad for your cat (though I have no clue how one pills a cat). Some vets also recommend it for artitis (our dog's on it). Once again though, these things are a lot more concentrated, than, well a fish, and might have side effects.

Your cat is [*unlikely* to need b6 supplements](https://www.dsm.com/markets/anh/en_US/Compendium/companion_animals/vitamin_B6.html), and if I recall correctly, as a water-soluble nutrient, is likely to get excreted in excess. Also, not sure why it would make your cat 'smarter'.

I can't find any specific examples of 5-HTP being good/bad for cats, but apparently [its lethal for dogs](http://aspcapro.org/resource/shelter-health-poison-control/top-5-most-deadly-medications-2015) - do check with a vet. However, chemically calming your companion animal sounds like a bad idea and you might rather sort out what is actually stressing her.

In addition to the main substances you mentioned, other things like sweeteners and fillers  would be potentially poisonous if its products meant for humans.

Answer (score 2):

Never give cat human vitamins. It is extremely dangerous and potentially life threatening.

Consult a vet and buy vitamin supplements made for cats only.

Some important points to mention:

- Overdose of Vitamin A and vitamin A toxicity is more common in house cats than deficiency.
- High doses of vitamin C can also cause problems in the urinary tract, mouth, and stomach.
- It's difficult to find the right balance between calcium and vitamin D. Too much can be toxic.

And countless more ....